# не показывает ошибки в рабочей области VS CODE

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

подскажите пожалуйста как исправить данную ошибку ? пишу код на c++ и если есть явная ошибка в коде,допустим пропуск - ;  то в рабочей области показует что я забыл про это.Но сейчас начал писать код на java и не показывает ничего,даже на самой явной ошибке.Что посоветуете сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мои плагины

Comment: Установить в VS Code поддержку Java. [Java in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java)

Comment: даже если у меня есть плагины которые на фото выше?\

Comment: @egor, по цвету текста создается впечатление, что у вас самый нижний плагин ([Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java)) деактивирован. Если это так, то естественно поддержки Java не будет.

Comment: а что конкретно скачать надо?jdk у меня есть.Java coding Pack скачать?

Comment: скачал но ничего не показывает @AlexanderPetrov